# Customize response object using webclient

Tags: java, webclient

I get some issue with customize response in WebClient

api http://x.x.x.x:8085/campaign/syncapi have request body :

```json
{
    "data": {
        "SmsAlias": "hhaahaaaaa"
    },
    "sms_code": "theeeee",
    "id": 9,
    "sms_contents": {
    "Contents": \["tetsssssssss", "qwerty", "qwert", "wert" \]
    },
    "client_code": "qwergh"
}
```

the response:

```
{
    "Error": {
        "Code": 200,
        "Message": "Sync campaign sms success"
    }
}
```

I need to build a system that call the api using java webclient. My code:

```java
@Bean
public WebClient webClient(){
    return WebClient.builder().baseUrl("http://10.144.13.155:8085").defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE).build();
}

@PostMapping("/campaign/sync")
public Mono\<ResponseGeneral\> getCampaignSMS(@RequestBody CampaignSMS campaignSMS, HttpServletRequest request){
    String requestTokenHeader = request.getHeader(AUTHORIZATION);
    String token = requestTokenHeader.substring(7);
    System.out.println(token);
    return webClient.post()
            .uri("/campaign/sync")
            .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
            .body(Mono.just(campaignSMS), CampaignSMS.class)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(ResponseGeneral.class);
}

public class CampaignSMS {
    private CampaignSMSData data;
    private String sms_code;
    private String id;
    private SMSContent sms_contents;
    private String client_code;
    private String client_campaign_code;
    private String name;
    private int product_type;
    private int channel;
    private String start_date;
    private String end_start;
    //constructor + getter setter
}

public class CampaignSMSData {
    private String SmsAlias;
    //constructor + getter setter
}

public class SMSContent {
    private String\[\] Contents;
    private int EncodeContent;
    private int Segment;
    //constructor + getter setter
}

public class ErrorData {
    private int Code;
    private String Message;
}

public class ResponseGeneral {
    private ErrorData Error;
    //constructor + getter setter
}
```

But I receive a respose like:

```
{
    "error": null
}
```

Comment: Please provide an [mre] and go into more details about what exactly it is you have tried

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! we cant be sure what made the server returns `error: null` given we have no access to the server. its a server problem, hence we cant reproduce your problem at all.